# disabling multibox using jquery

Tags: jquery, multibox

I have a multibox in a jsp page.I wanted to create a jquery function that if more than 3 transactions are choosen, then the rest of the checkboxes(rendered from the multibox) would be disabled.I have written the foolowing code.When I tested it in a checkbox (input type checkbox ) it worked but it is not working for multiboxes

```
<html:multibox property="selectedTxns" styleClass="txnList" >
                                            <bean:write name="Id" property="businessTypeVOId"/>
                                        </html:multibox>
```

jquery function-->

```
<script>
function countChecked() {
var n = $(".txnList:checked").length;

          if (n<3) {     $(".txnList:checkbox").removeAttr("disabled"); 
                                                    $("#msg").text(""); 
                                       }
                                     else {     $(".txnList:checkbox:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true);
                                                $("#msg").text("can not choose more than 3 transactions");
                                     }
                                  }

                                  $(".txnList:checkbox").click(countChecked);
                                </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your logic ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cUJwf/1/)) and it's working.

I don't know how the multibox is rendered but is `.txnList` the container holding
the checkboxes?

If so, you need put a space inbetween the container and checkbox selector like this:

`.txnList :checkbox` and `.txnList :checked`

This will select the container THEN the checkbox.

Hope that helps.